# Processing images in YUV

Tags: image, image-processing, lookup, yuv

I have RGB LUT, so I  know about the new color of pixels, but this RGB LUT has only 33*33*33 values. So if I have point, which didn't contain in LUT, I find 8 corner vertices in the cube of LUT, which contain this point, and approx their colors.

But now I have YUV image. I can transform YUV to RGB, find 8 neighboring vertices (8 corner vertices) in RGB, approx their colors and transform to YUV back. But it's too long.

So previously I transform all 33*33*33 RGB LUT values to YUV [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0A3u.png). And if I have the point, I have to find 8 corner vertices among these transform values. But I can't understand how to do it quickly?

Comment: The RGB - YUV transform is linear and will be faster if implemented the straight way rather than using a LUT.

Comment: "Thinning out" in the title is misleading as it has nothing to do with the question. You should fix that.

Comment: I have fixed. What is "the straight way"?

Comment: Using the formula.

Comment: But how I can don't use LUT?

Comment: How do you work with a LUT ?

Comment: If I have the point in RGB, I find 8 neighboring corner vertices in cube from RGB LUT vertices, after approx colors these corner vertices and so I get new color of that point.

Comment: So if you are able to get or set the color of a point, you must be able to apply the formula.